# Word pair cooccurence

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to count word pairs within the same line
So If the sentence is
"How many many people die
How many"
Expected (How,many)= 3 But my program somehow doesn't add the pair from the same line and Result (How,many) = 2

```
val lines = streamingContext.textFileStream(inputDir)

lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    val pairs = rdd.map(_.split(" ")
       .map(_.trim).toList)
       .flatMap(_.combinations(2).map{pairs=>(pairs.mkString("-"), 1)})
       .reduceByKey(_+_)
    
    if(!rdd.partitions.isEmpty)
       pairs.saveAsTextFile(output + System.currentTimeMillis())
    
    val collectedCounts = pairs.collect
    collectedCounts.foreach(c => println(c))
})
```

Comment: Hi Deathnote! Welcome :) could you include the output of what you're currently seeing?